# How to replace > 1 tokens on a string?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have a list of `tokens`

```
 [@date]
 [@time]
 [@fileName]
 ... etc
```

That are dispersed all over a large file. I can parse the file and replace them with `Regex.Replace` easily when there's only one token on a line. However the problem arises when there's two tokens on one line
example:

```
[@date] [@time]
```

What I thought about doing is using `String.Split` with `" " as the delimiter`, and then iterate through the result checking if there are tokens.

But I see two problems with this approach, the file is rather large and this would definitely impact performance. The second problem is that the file that will be outputted is a `SQL` file and I'd like to retain the white space just for looks.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem? Or is it just another case of premature optimization?

Comment: What is wrong in using `Regex` for two tokens in a line?

Comment: If RegEx is not required I submitted an answer.  Although I agree with llya, I'm not sure why RegEx would have an issue replacing a specified value that shows up twice on a line.  Sina Iravanian's answer should work.

Comment: @ Ilya Ivanov Could you clarify what you mean with an answer?
I'm still fairly new with regex

Comment: @Wusiji it's not an answer, it's a question apparently. Sorry, but I don't understand your problem, specially when it comes to inefficiency of regular expressions to handle many tokes on single line. Could you give high-level description of your problem, give your implementation code, state what is the desired outcome and also give some examples of your sql scripts, in which  you want to replace tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is that instead of replacing patterns line by line, replace them in the whole file:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, pattern1, replacement1);
...
fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, patternN, replacementN);
```

Comment: Magcially fixed everything when I didn't iterate through all the lines individually

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is to store tokens and their values separately and then to iterate over them replacing your query with values for that tokens. Example is given below:

```
var tokensWithValues = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"[@date]", DateTime.Now},
    {"[@time]", DateTime.Now.Ticks},
    {"[@fileName]", "myFile.xml"},
};

var sqlQuery = File.ReadAllText("mysql.sql");

foreach (var tokenValue in tokensWithValues)
{
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Replace(tokenValue.Key, tokenValue.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the string.Replace(...) extension.  That would allow you to Replace all instances of a string.

for example

```
string file = File.ReallAllText("myfile.txt");


file.Replace("[@date]", "replaced_value");
```

the above would replace all instances of "[@date]" with "replaced_value".

*Edited as previous answer included custom extensions not available to OP.  Thanks llya.*

Comment: it won't compile, `string.Replace` takes either two chars or two strings, not a List of string and a string. You probably want to chain that calls

Comment: `ReplaceAll` - isn't it's not a part of BCL? just curious

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question asks about replacing multiple tokens with multiple strings (eg., `[@date]` with today's date, `[@time]` with the current time, etc.). I'm also pretty sure that `File` doesn't have a `ReallAllText` method. :-)

Comment: @llya: Haha wow yes,  It is a part of my own extension collection.  I wasn't paying attention when I wrote out the code where the extension was being called from.  However, Replace is the way to go without the IEnumerable<> passed in like you mentioned.  I'll update accordingly.